# How to define VARCHAR columns to support special characters?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In my table `product` I have a column: `product_name` with type `VARCHAR` and size of 100: `product_name varchar(100)`

When I try to insert a name with special characters like this one:

```
°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%°°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°%âä°
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:78 : logExceptions() : Error for batch element #1: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

My product_name column can have 100 characters, for me 'â' is 1 character.

Is there in DB2 another type (other than `varchar`), to set it for the `product_name` column?

thus I can execute this query:

```
alter table product alter column product_name set data type otherType(100);
```

Comment: Which OS and wich DB2 version? Characters and Bytes are two different measures. The solution depends on the answers to my question or simply increase the "100".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 VARCHAR unicode data storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385183/db2-varchar-unicode-data-storage)

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher, I'm using  DB2 10.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the

```
STRING_UNITS
```

database configuration parameter. You can use it to switch fronm the default byte length to a character length. This mean char(100) will be default interpreted by DB2 as 100 Bytes. As chracter in a unicode database can span 1-4 bytes 100 bytes are not enough to store 100 chars. After switching to STRING_UNITS = CODEUNITS32 you get 100 chars when defining a column varchar(100).
So you do not need another type but another db cfg setting.

Comment: @junior -- note that this is in essence equivalent to declaring `product_name` as  `varchar(400 octets)`, and it will affect all table columns and SQL PL variables in the database. This is not an issue with `VARCHAR` columns, because they won't allocate more space than needed, but `CHAR` columns _will_ allocate four times more space.